# PYTHON Remove repetitive chars from string

Tags: python

I have a string name = "Aaron" and would like to remove all the vowels. I am using remove() but if the char is repetive like letter 'a' in this case it stays in the string. Any suggestions ? Here is my code  :

```
def disemvowel(word):
    word_as_list = list(word.lower())
    print(word_as_list)
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    for char in word_as_list:
        for v in vowels : 
            if char == v : 
                word_as_list.remove(v)
    return "".join(word_as_list)

print(disemvowel("Aaaron"))
```

Comment: `word = "".join([c for c in word if c.lower() not in "aeiou"])`

Comment: This is not the case.

Comment: You can efficiently remove (or modify) multiple characters in a _string_ with the [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method. Eg, `novowels = {ord(c): None for c in 'AEIOUaeiou'}; my_string.translate(novowels)`

Comment: BTW, I _love_ your function name. :)

Comment: FWIW, another way to make the translation table is `novowels = str.maketrans('','','AEIOUaeiou')`. See the second linked question above for more details.

Comment: Thanks guys . I wasn't aware of list comprehension. Seems to be a very elegant and natural to read approach.

Comment: List comprehensions are awesome. They're an essential item in the Python toolkit. There are also dict and set comprehensions. And then there are generator expressions which are similar to list comprehensions, except they allow you to iterate over a sequence of items without having to create the sequence in RAM.

Comment: Giving an alternate, working solution does nothing to help OP understand why his approach doesn't work. Teach people why, don't hand out answers with no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As other people have said, list comprehension is the way to go:

```
def disemvowel(word):
    word = word.lower()
    vowels = ["a" , "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    return "".join([char for char in word if char not in vowels])  
print disemvowel("Aaaallbag")
```

Comment: This technique is great for a general list, but to delete or replace characters in a string the `.translate` method is _much_ faster because it does the looping and processing with compiled code, so it runs at C speed. FWIW, an alternate list comp approach is `d = dict.fromkeys('AEIOUaeiou', ''); newdata = ''.join([d.get(c, c) for c in data])`.

Comment: This answer will lowercase any consonant that may have been uppercase. That may not be what you want.

Comment: Yep. It's what the OP was doing, so I followed suit with what he wanted.